# Structuring an MVC application - Model and Data Access

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm rewriting a web app in MVC and I am trying not to get hung up on the architecture, but then, MVC has patters which I want to stick to

My application has views which display data retrieved from a database.

Normally, I would write my controller action as follows

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new IndexModel();
    model = DbHelper.GetData(); // business layer
    return View(model);
}
```

But I have been doing some reading saying that data access should be done in the model, so is something like this better?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new IndexModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

And IndexModel:

```
public class IndexModel
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set;}
    public IndexModel()
    {
        // Fetch data in here...
        EmailAddress = DbHelper.GetEmail(); // for example
    }
}
```

So, should the controller include the logic to fetch the data, or should the model handle it? A lot of the MSDN examples show the controller populating the model, but that seems to break the layers of MVC

Answer (score 3):

The question is somehow opinion based. But considering the following ideas may help:

**Model**

- Let it be responsible for transferring data between layers.
- Use plain classes as *View Models* or *Input Models*.
- Don't put business logic or data-access into model classes.

**View**

- Let it be responsible for rendering the UI.
- Just use `Model` and don't call business logic classes directly.

**Controller**

- Let it be responsible for handling requests and providing response. Also responsible for controlling flow of application.
- Controllers should only call Business Logic methods and they should not contain any business logic
- Don't interact with Data Access Layer directly. Let this Business Logic Layet take this responsibility.

**Business Logic**

- Let it be responsible for business operations like changing data, processing data, search and loading data.
- Use data access layer methods for CRUD operations. Don't rely on database directly. Let Data Access Layer handle CRUD operations.
- Create each business method as a single unit of work which

**Data Access**

- Let it be responsible for CRUD operations with data.
- While you can use a ORM instead of this layer, but in a large application, you can also create this layer as layer which uses ORM.

**General considerations**

- Create abstractions for different layers.
- Controller should rely on Models and Business Logic Abstractions.
- Business Logic should rely on Models and Data Access Layer Abstractions.
- Data Access layers should rely on Models and ORM
- You can use different model types for different layers or create a shared model library.
- You can have a shared library for cross cutting concerns like log.

Comment: What you decribed as a Model is just simple POCO or DTO. Wikipedia definition of Model says that model: "directly manages the data, logic and rules of the application." I have also seen that model should be responsible for data access. So how is it?

Comment: @BartekChyży POCOs also are a kind of model. Models having Business logic usually are considered as Domain models (in DDD). Here I am talking ASP.NET MVC (as an Application Framework). In ASP.NET MVC, in an N-Layered architecture, in addition to have a reference to Domain Models or Business Models, you need to define View Models and Input Models. View models represents data which you are going to show inside the views and Input models represents data which you are going to receive in your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

**MVC (Model View Controller)** is a broader design pattern governing the ASP.NET MVC applications architecture, but **its not the only pattern** a given application shall stick to. The ultimate goal is to have **neat and clean code**, **loosely coupled artifacts** and focus on **code re-usability**.

Usually my approach to project architecture is have a separate project for **Data-Access Layer**(usually a class library project) and another for **Business-Layer (to implement business-level decisions)** (also a class library project) and an **ASP.NET MVC project** as a **Presentation-Layer** project . The Business-Layer project has a dll reference of Data-Access project and Presentation-Layer project (ASP.NET MVC Project) shall have references of both Data-Access and Business-Layer projects.

Now I use dependency injection approach to provide data-access dependencies to controllers in their constructor, something like this

```
private IDbHelper dbHelper;
public HomeController(IDbHelper _dbHelper)
{
    dbHelper=_dbHelper;
}
```

So the db-access class shall be made available through a dependency injector (Ninject for example) and the individual action methods shall not have to worry about how to create objects. Now your action method shall simply make calls to the dbHelper class like this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
return View(dbHelper.GetData());
}
```

Also please note that besides using **Models** your application shall need to create **View-Models (VMs)** (Models returned from database and modified by business layer to meet the business specific needs).

So in short a good project is a combination of several different patterns and architecture styles that are implemented to make the code re-usable, neat and clean and easy for testing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using dependency injection, especially if you're going to be doing a lot of unit testing (e.g., with Moq). Obaid (user who made a post above) posted good information about this.

See the following reference for more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Note: As shown in the above reference, you will need to configure your services in your Startup class (or whichever type you chose to configure all of your services for MVC).